# How Outlook add 'x' at the end of input field?

Tags: angularjs, outlook, outlook-addin, office-js

#### Problem

`Outlook` adds `x` at the end of an input field in `Outlook add-in` panel when I enter data and binds a `click` event to it that clears the data in it.

I need to add logic to the click event, but I can't find that `x` in the DOM.

#### Environment

- Windows 10
- Outlook 2010 (looks like it is not depending on the version)

#### Reproduce

When **User** clicks on `x` then data will be removed from `input-field` but data will remain in `$scope.email` because of the angular `$watch` not working.

I am looking for pointers on:

- How `Outlook` adds `x` at the end of input field?
- How I can handle a clear event in my page? I can't find this `x` in DOM while inspecting?

#### Screenshot

[Outlook added 'x' at end of input field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBYfq.png)

Comment: Your question should contain the angularjs tag. 
This is input and button field add to one div with style like input. If you want catch button click in template add ng-click to button `ng-click="myfunction()">` and create $scope.myfunction() in directive.

Comment: Thanks @ambussh, I tried and added ng-click function in input field and div but Outlook add 'x' when user any value present in input file and input filed was focused but when I click on 'x' after attached `ng-click` event then `myfunction()` not executed

Comment: I tried to load any other website instead of my page then same **'x'** will be added by `Outlook` in every field

Comment: If you don't show us some code, all that we can do is guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Office` `uifTextfield` directive so that when the user clicks on the `"X"` a the right of the input field to clear the value it is reflected in the model bound to it

```
app.directive('uifTextfield', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: ['uifTextfield', '?ngModel'],
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
            $(elem).find("input").bind("mouseup", function(event) {
                var $inputElement = $(this);
                if ($inputElement.val()) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        if (!$inputElement.val()) {
                            angular.element($inputElement).controller('ngModel').$setViewValue('');
                        }
                    }, 1);
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In template add:

```
<div class="input-new">
  <input ng-model="textValue" ng-focus="isFocused=true" ng-blur="blur()" /> 
  <button ng-show="isFocused && textValue.length > 0" ng-click="cleanText()">X</button>
</div>
```

in controller add:

```
$scope.isFocused = false;
$scope.textValue = "";

$scope.cleanText = function() {
   $scope.textValue = "";
}

$scope.blur = function() {
    $timeout( function(){
        $scope.isFocused = false;
    }, 200 ); 
}
```

Of course you must add style to input and div box.

[Workin example in plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/TOG41Ltg9demdQRJKt62?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you @ambussh I tried your solution on Chrome and other browser and find the 'x' you added manually is working fine in Chrome but it shows two cross in IE. If I used your IE browser cross then value of `textValue` in scope was not updated.

Comment: Because IE adds its own X by default. You can disable support for your button for MS browsers or disable their button. `.input-new input::-ms-clear { display: none; }`  . Show code because I do not know why it does not work in your app. The example I have prepared works for me on Chrome, Safari, Edge and IE. [Example with disabled IE and Edge input cross](https://plnkr.co/edit/9UJap6zElPVJvbAc1gxD?p=preview)